# Greet a FB user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

First off I'm new & learning everyday, I would really appreciate any help :)

- I own a fb fanpage & I plan to drive my fans to an external website temporary one :- (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101978000/index.html) I own.
- I simply want to greet my fb users on my website i.e (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101978000/index.html) who are already logged in to fb, as I would post status updates and get my fans to visit my website.

Eg :-

- Welcome, (Mike) to my website.
- Hello, (Jason) good morning.

Can someone help me with the code or guide me please, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset ($user))
    echo "Welcome, $user[name] to my website.";
```

`$user` is the variable created on user login that has all the user info.

Comment: Hey Eisa, this is my link :
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101978000/index.html
Its not coming up, can you check the above link and help me please. I'm already logged in to fb if this helps.

Comment: Oh Ok..I really dont know php, could you code this for me, I'm really trying to make this work :(

Comment: Make this code? It isn't as easy as it looks. I assumed you were logging users in with the Facebook API.

Comment: Actually what you're exactly trying to do is impossible, unless you have a complete login system and the user then logs in.

Comment: Okay no I'm not I just want to greet the user thats all to be honest. (username) good morning or (username) good afternoon ya know..